# How to use DoubleToVisibilityConverter in uwp

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, scrollviewer, converters

DoubleToVisibilityConverter can be used to easily change a double value to a Visibility based one based on a given threshold value. If both GreaterThan and LessThan are set, the converter will set the visibility if the target value is in-between those two values. Otherwise, it will look for the target being greater than or less than the specified value.

so my question is ----

***How to use DoubleToVisibilityConverter for scrollviewer as i want to hide (back to Top)Button and scrollbar is at last down position and when scrollbar is going to up it will show the button.***

i am using back to top button for scroll to top.

[ same as working in many website (scrollUp Button) ]

Below one is ***MainPage.xaml***

XAML - Page Resource

```
<Page.Resources>
   <converters:DoubleToVisibilityConverter x:Key="GreaterThanToleranceVisibilityConverter" GreaterThan="65.0"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

XAML - Ui Element

```
<Button x:name="Scroll_To_Up_Button" Visibility="{Binding ScrollableHeight, Converter{StaticResourceGreaterThanToleranceVisibilityConverter}/>
```

where i have to add

> ScrollableHeight

in ***MainPage.xaml.cs*** and how to use in MyUWP App.

Comment: Please guys help me..................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding a parameter eg.

```
<Button x:name="Scroll_To_Up_Button" Visibility="{Binding ScrollableHeight, Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanToleranceVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=42/>
```

**Edit:**

Give your page a name:

```
<Page Name="thisPage"
      ... >
```

Then point your binding source to it to access the dependency property `ScrollableHeight` if that is the type you declared it:

```
<Button x:name="Scroll_To_Up_Button" Visibility="{Binding ScrollableHeight, ElementName=thisPage, Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanToleranceVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=42/>
```

And the dependency property in `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollableHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ScrollableHeight), typeof(int), typeof(*NAMEOFYOURPAGE*), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public int ScrollableHeight
{
    get => (int)GetValue(ScrollableHeightProperty);
    set => SetValue(ScrollableHeightProperty, value);
}
```

Comment: No my question is how to bind "ScrollableHeight" in MainPage.xaml.cs means what code should i write in MainPage.xaml.cs for binding a scrollviewer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write code in `MainPage.xaml.cs` for the binding of `DoubleToVisibilityConverter`. You could set the `GreaterThan` property or `LessThan` property of a `DoubleToVisibilityConverter` instance in `MainPage.xaml` file. And you should bind the `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset` property which gets the distance the content has been scrolled vertically instead of [ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.scrollableheight?view=winrt-19041) property which is a constant if the content of the ScrollViewer is determined.

You could refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/converters#doubletovisibilityconverter-examples) for the usage of `DoubleToVisibilityConverter`.

Please check the following code as a sample:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:DoubleToVisibilityConverter x:Key="GreaterThanToleranceVisibilityConverter" 
     GreaterThan="100" TrueValue="Visible" FalseValue="Collapsed"/>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Width="300" Height="300" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
        <TextBlock Text="111122222222222222222222222222222222211111111111111111111111111" 
                   Width="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button x:Name="Scroll_To_Up_Button" Content="back to up" Click="Scroll_To_Up_Button_Click" Margin="10"
            Visibility="{Binding VerticalOffset,ElementName=scrollViewer,
        Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanToleranceVisibilityConverter},FallbackValue=Collapsed,
        TargetNullValue=Collapsed
          }"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I got my answer........................thanks all of you to help me